# Android: add onclick on text in canvas?

Tags: android, canvas

In a custom view I design a text with drawText function. Now, I would intercepted the click on the text. this my code:

```
float x = (float)position.getX() + Constants.RADIUS + Constants.OFFSET_OVER_ARCH;
float y = (float)position.getY() ;
for (String line : node.getNode().getLabel().split(Constants.CHAR_SEPARATOR)) {   
   canvas.drawText(line, x, y, paintSele);
   y += paintSele.descent() - paintSele.ascent();
}
```

Draw rectangle in the text and check if the coordinates of the click is on the rectangle area? This a better solution?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can measure text, and get text bounds (which is Rect). No need to draw another rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, work fine :-)

Comment: Fine! Will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do, is to [`Paint.measureText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)), then [`Paint.getTextBound()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#getTextBounds(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Rect)) of the text which will fill the inputted `Rect` with the text's coordinates, and then listen for clicks in that rectangle.